# django social all auth - multiple user type

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-3.0, django-4.0

I have two Registration pages: Register as **Buyer**, Register as **Seller**.

on both Pages , I've included Normal Registration and social authentication using Google and Facebook.

I've added social authentication using Django all-auth, but cannot get user_role.

[1][Registration Page]:

- after Registration : user is redirected to home page and as there is no user_role set in social authentication , one cannot access Buyer or Seller 's section.

[2][Signup with Google]: After signup : User is registered as Blank Login.

- check home page after Google signup:

**MY TASK** : Is to assign user_type on both the buttons: **Buyer** and **Seller**. on click button redirect user to its particular Registration Page and Login/Signup with Social Authentication and after Successful-Login Redirect User to its Page and show **user_type** in *Django-administration-panel* as:

### User_type   |   Email         |   is_active

Buyer      | test@gmail.com  |     True

Seller     | demo@gmail.com  |     False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can create a profile model for all users and then give the user a profile like this.

#models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user_type = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="profile")
```

this will run after the user has created.

#signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from . models import Profile
from django.conf import settings

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance, user_type=instance.user_type)
```

edit: I don't know how is your user_type field I assume it is "user_type"